# Javascript that act like css3 transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to do something like `-moz-transition` effect that give me a animated rotate picture. or move a picture from bottom of it's wrapper to top of it.

for clarify how I want just take a look at [This Link](http://demo.scripteers.com/expressive/) and see the four pictures that are under slider.

It uses `-moz-transition` CSS3 effect but I want to have something with js or jQuery to animate it even in IE.

Is there any plugin for it?

Thanks alot

Comment: Why not just use transitions and use a fallback for IE?

Comment: The answer you selected uses `transition`. I thought you were looking for a Javascript method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.animate()` will do this in a cross-browser way.

```js
$( '.button' ).animate( { top: '-=50' }, 400 );
```

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/) seems to perfectly fit to your needs.